Get Android Screen Size
As I'm trying to build an android app in Andriod Studio, from the following options which is the best way to find the actual Screen Size available ( landscape, full screen ) and to not truncate the UIs:

Option 1: Using DisplayMetrics
Option 2: Using WindowMetrics (API 30+)
Option 3: Using Resources
Using View (Root View Dimensions)


use WindowMetrics. It provides WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics()

Focus on the window size, not the screen size. You may not have access to the full screen: split-screen mode on phones, freeform multi-window mode on notebooks/tablets, foldables, etc.
